# `FormControl` set value by method not enables field, how to mark as valid

Tags: angular5

I am setting the senderAddress by dynamic in my form. But still the `submit` button not enables.

here is my html:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Senders's Address" 
            formControlName="senderAddress" #searchSenderAddress>
```

in ts:

```
@ViewChild("searchSenderAddress") public searchSenderAddressRef:ElementRef;
senderAddress = new FormControl("", [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^\S*$/)]);

ngOnInit() {

        if( this.senderFormattedAddress ){
            this.senderAddress.setValue( this.senderFormattedAddress ); //setting the value
        }
    }
```

Is there any issue with my formController?

**UPDATE**

I try with this way:

```
ngOnInit() {

        if( this.senderFormattedAddress ){
            this.senderAddress.setValue( this.senderFormattedAddress );
            this.senderAddress.markAsTouched();
        }
    }
```

still no luck!

Answer (score 0):

It's seems some bad from my side:

the validator pattern like: `senderAddress = new FormControl("", [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^\S*$/)]);` I kept made the issue.

now I removed replaced with:

```
senderAddress = new FormControl("", [Validators.required]);
```

Now works fine.